Why do I get TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array even though I am passing 1-d array?
I have a dataframe (new_df) with below data:
Unnamed: 0       Words                                          embedding
0            0    Elephant  [-0.017855134320424067, -0.008739002273680945,...
1            1        Lion  [-0.001514446088710819, -0.010011047775235734,...
2            2       Tiger  [-0.013417221828848814, -0.009594874215361255,...
3            3         Dog  [-0.0009933243881749651, -0.015114395874422861...
4            4     Cricket  [0.003905495127549335, -0.0072066829816015395,...
5            5     Footbal  [-0.011442505362835323, -0.008127146122306163,...

I am picking value of the dataframe as
text_embedding  = new_df["embedding"][1]

Now when I run the below snippet for calculating some value:
import numpy as np
def cosine_similarity(A, B):

    # Calculate dot product
    dot_product = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(A, B))

    # Calculate the magnitude of each vector
    magnitude_A = sum(a*a for a in A)**0.5
    magnitude_B = sum(b*b for b in B)**0.5
    cosine_similarity = dot_product / (magnitude_A * magnitude_B)
    print(f"Cosine Similarity using standard Python: {cosine_similarity}")

array1 = np.array(new_df['embedding'][0])
array2 = np.array(text_embedding)

cosine_similarity(array1,array2)

I get this Error:
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[13], line 29
         25 array2 = np.array(text_embedding)
         27 #print(array1)
         28 #print(array2)
    ---> 29 cosine_similarity(array1,array2)
         31 #cosine_similarity([1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2],[1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,2,2,2,2,2])
         32 
         33 #df
    
    Cell In[13], line 10, in cosine_similarity(A, B)
          7 def cosine_similarity(A, B):
          8 
          9     # Calculate dot product
    ---> 10     dot_product = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(A, B))
         12     # Calculate the magnitude of each vector
         13     magnitude_A = sum(a*a for a in A)**0.5
    
    TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

When I try the below code, its working fine:
cosine_similarity([1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2],[1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,2,2,2,2,2])

I don't understand why I get this error when taking the lists from my dataframe. Both the variables are 1-D arrays, so I'm not sure why its failing with array1,array2 while passing with values manually provided.

I ran it using a small example and it worked fine.  Are you sure that there isn't an empty list within your embedding column that you may be accidentally calling? The error suggests the function is trying to iterate over an empty arry

while debugging both text_embedding and new_df['embedding'][0] do showing data in form of
[-0.017855134320424067, -0.008739002273680945,......]
&
[-0.017855134320424067, -0.008739002273680945,... ]

And does running type(text_embedding) and type(df['embedding'][0]) say list as well? and len(text_embedding) and len(df['embedding'][0]) are also greater than 0?

To my surprise - type(new_df['embedding'][0]) & type(text_embedding) both are returning Str instead of list :O

That'll be your problem :p

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You just need to convert your embedded column into lists, or convert the values before passing into the function.  This question  should help with how to do that

Thanks @EmiOB for debugging this error . this was the error which you pointed . Everything was a string and not an list or array which was causing this.

As Suggested by @EmiOB in comments problem was with type of new_df['embedding'][0] and text_embedding . Both were returning Strings like this '[1.0, 1.1 ,1.2]' instead of array like [1.0, 1.1 ,1.2]
changed the code to below
from ast import literal_eval
array1 = literal_eval(text_embedding)
array2 = literal_eval(new_df['embedding'][0])

and it returned array of floats instead of String earlier.

Did you load this frame from a csv?  Cells with arrays or lists are saved a strings to csv.  The defautt dataframe display omits quotes, so it's hard to tell just from the display whether they are actually lists or a look-alike string.

yes you are absolutely right . i used csv file to populate my dataframe objects. i guess there  was the issue which was making it as string instead of array

This unexpected string conversion when using csv, has been discussed in a number of SO.   I think there are better ways of saving a dataframe; pickle for one.
